# avcodec_send_packet high memory usage

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding

So for a while now I have been making something like a video player application. The video player receives a video stream, decodes it and displays its contents. I am writing it in java using the ffmpeg wrapper (this should not be of any real significance I am just mentioning that because the code I provide will be in java but the functions that I am using just make calls to the relevant c/c++ functions of the ffmpeg library). The issue is that when I call avcodec_send_packet it nets me a very high memory usage which also scales with the resolution of the video. Most recently I tried decoding a 4k video stream and every call to avcodec_send_packet netted me about 40 mb of memory usage. This stabilizes after the first frame. In other words when I receive the frame the memory usage stops climbing for subsequent frames. For that particular 4k video stream it climbed to about 800 mb and for subsequent avcodec_send_packet and avcodec_receive_frame calls the memory usage doesn't significantly climb. If the resolution is 1080p it nets me about 300 megabytes of memory. This is a pretty high memory usage considering that one decoded 4k YUV420 frame is about 12 megabytes

```java
    public Optional<Boolean> decodeVideoFrame(AVPacket pkt,boolean readPacket,boolean keyFrames,boolean doProcessing) throws Exception {
        int ret;
        // Decode video frame
        if (readPacket) {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(video_c, pkt);
            if (pkt.data() == null && pkt.size() == 0) {
                pkt.stream_index(-1);
            }
            if (ret == AVERROR_EAGAIN() || ret == AVERROR_EOF()) {
                // The video codec may have buffered some frames
            } else if (ret < 0) {
                // Ignore errors to emulate the behavior of the old API
                // throw new Exception("avcodec_send_packet() error " + ret + ": Error sending a video packet for decoding.");
            }
        }

        // Did we get a video frame?
        while (true) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(video_c, picture);

            if (ret == AVERROR_EAGAIN() || ret == AVERROR_EOF()) {
                if (pkt.data() == null && pkt.size() == 0) {
                    return Optional.empty();
                } else {
                    return Optional.of(true);

                }
            } else if (ret < 0) {
                // Ignore errors to emulate the behavior of the old API
                // throw new Exception("avcodec_receive_frame() error " + ret + ": Error during video decoding.");
                return Optional.of(true);

            }
```

This is pretty much all the relevant code along with maybe the packet allocation:

```java
  AVPacket pkt = av_packet_alloc();

            pkt.stream_index(-1);
            int ret;
            while(true){
                if((ret = av_read_frame(grabber.getFormatContext(),pkt))<0){

                    if (ret == AVERROR_EAGAIN()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                            continue;
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            // reset interrupt
                            Thread.interrupted();

                        }
                    }
                    av_packet_unref(pkt);
                    pkt.deallocate();
                    return null;

                }
                break;

            }


            return pkt;
```

(this is in a separate method). Also another weird effect that comes out of this is when the video resolution is higher than 1080p the frames gets corrupted. I will attach two images that compare what the frame is supposed to look like and what it actually looks like.[What its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pT9C.jpg)
[What it looks like when given to the decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8vPM.png)
And in case the question is asked this isn't because of how I am displaying the frame. I can say that with 100% certainty as I have moved across 3 different ways of rendering video frames. The first one being CanvasFrame that comes with the wrapper library I am using for ffmpeg, then I switched to javafx ImageView and now I am using vulkan. Same exact result across all three methods. The decoder is pretty much in all cases vp9 and the frames are in yuv420p.

I tried looking through stackoverflow and some other places and I saw a somewhat similar post but unfortunately I couldn't really find an answer there.

Update: I decided to implement hardware acceleration in my program while this problem persists to see if its going to help. With hardware acceleration the memory usage is significantly lower but that's to be expected. The more bizarre thing I came across is this: The frames are still corrupted when resolution is above 1080p EXCEPT if I very specifically say

```java
avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("vp9_cuvid");
```

. If I use this :

```java
av_find_best_stream(oc, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, vidCodec, 0);
```

this also allocates the video codec and it uses vp9 but the frames get corrupted. no idea what's going on. I also tried doing

```java
avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("vp9");
```

but that also leaves me with corrupted frames. (it should be the same codec after all).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to correctly dereference the video frame using `av_frame_free` when you are finished using it.

Each decoder requires some overhead to store reference frames, which might be one source of the high memory usage you are observing. It's nearly impossible to influence this from the consumer side. When you are in control of the encoding step of this video, you can modify some parameters (eg. keyframe distance) to lower the memory overhead of the decoder.

Another thing I noticed: When you receive `AVERROR_EAGAIN` from `avcodec_send_packet`, you need to make sure, that you send this packet again after you have collected a frame with `avcodec_receive_frame`. Otherwise you will receive artefact in subsequent frames (however, this does not explain the corrupted frames you mentioned).

The corrupted frames are most likely due to wrong YUV -> RGB conversion. Maybe some data is missing (U and/or V-plane). However, there is no code to give any judgements.

Comment: I am reusing the same AVFrame for the whole duration of the application. And unfortunately that isn't the cause as this problem occurs before the frame is even received in the first place. I pause with the debugger on the avcodec_send_packet line and I observe the memory usage. When I step over the line the memory usage goes +40mb. This repeats a few times until the call to avcodec_receive_frame is finally successful

Comment: Oh also something I forgot to mention in my previous comment I have no control over the encoding process but I can assure you its not because of that. Not to mention that still leaves the frame corruption mystery which I feel like if one of the problems is solved maybe that will solve the other problem as well.

Comment: you can try using another video with a different codec and see if you observe the same behavior

Comment: I tried 2 things. I downloaded a separate video that was originally encoded with h264 and played it. Memory usage still high (although its about 100-200 mb lower) but the more interesting part is the fragmentation no longer occurs. The image itself looks fine. After that I transcoded the original video from vp9 to h264 and played it. Same result, no idea what's going on. I know the usage isn't supposed to be that astronomically high because youtube uses vp9 and when you play videos on yt you don't see your memory skyrocket to like 800mb

Comment: just noticed that you edited your comment (I also edited my post) The YUV->RGB conversion is fine I can 100% guarantee that. Also if it returns EAGAIN I am sending the next packet in the stream (the decodeVideoFrame function is called with the next packet in the stream) And if you check the update on my post you will see that the full on hardware decoder (vp9_cuvid) works perfectly fine. If I use only hardware acceleration with vp9 though I still get weird frame corruption. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the software vp9 decoder.